# Testing Map<int, vector> with Google Test

Tags: c++, vector, googletest

These are in the `Game` header file of my class:
Order is another class.

```
std::map<int, std::vector<Order>> ordersToBeExecuted;
```

```
std::map<int, std::vector<Order>> getOrdersToBeExecuted();
```

and this is the definition in my cpp file:

```
std::map<int, std::vector<Order>> Game::getOrdersToBeExecuted()
{
    return this->ordersToBeExecuted;
}
```

Now, I don't know how to test this. I am trying Google Tests. I am writing this but currently, I get an error that:

```
#define EXPECT_EQ(val1,val2) EXPECT_PRED_FORMAT2(::testing::internal:: EqHelper<GTEST_IS_NULL_LITERAL_(val1)>::Compare, val1, val2)
Expands to:

EXPECT_PRED_FORMAT2(::testing::internal:: EqHelper<GTEST_IS_NULL_LITERAL_(std::map<0)>::Compare, std::map<0, std::vector<<Order>>)
expected a type specifier
```

```
TEST(gameTest, getOrdersToBeExecutedTest) {

    std::map<int, std::vector<Order>> first;
    std::vector<Order> orders;
    Game g;
    Order o1;
    Order o2;
    orders.push_back(o1);
    orders.push_back(o2);
    first[0] = orders;
    g.setNumberOfPlayers(1);

    EXPECT_EQ(std::map<0,std::vector<Order>>, g.getOrdersToBeExecuted());
}
```

Edit:

```
TEST(gameTest, getOrdersToBeExecutedTest) {

    std::map<int, std::vector<Order>> first;
    std::vector<Order> orders;
    std::vector<Order> orders2;
    Game g;
    Order o1, o2;
    Order o3, o4;
    orders.push_back(o1);
    orders.push_back(o2);
    orders2.push_back(o3);
    orders2.push_back(o4);
    first[0] = orders;
    first[1] = orders2;
    //EXPECT_EQ(first, g.getOrdersToBeExecuted());


EXPECT_THAT(g.getOrdersToBeExecuted()), ElementsAre(Pair(0, ElementsAre(o1, o2)), Pair(1, ElementsAre(o3, o4)));
}
```

I am trying to use but I still get these errors:

```
#define EXPECT_THAT(value,matcher) EXPECT_PRED_FORMAT1( ::testing::internal::MakePredicateFormatterFromMatcher(matcher), value)
Expands to:

EXPECT_PRED_FORMAT1( ::testing::internal::MakePredicateFormatterFromMatcher(), g.getOrdersToBeExecuted())
identifier "EXPECT_THAT" is undefined
```

Comment: `std::map<0,std::vector<<Order>>` has a typo (double `<<`) and is a type. You need to pass an object.

Comment: Could you give an example? I tried using ```first``` as the first argument but it doesn't work. @bolov

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To test containers use container matchers, see: https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/cheat_sheet.md

Map is a bit tricky, because it's a container of pairs, so you have to combine it with `Pair` matcher, for example:

```
using testing::ElementsAre;
using testing::Pair;

EXPECT_THAT(g.getOrdersToBeExecuted()), ElementsAre(Pair(key1, val1), Pair(key1, val2)));
```

When value type is `vector`, you need to put container matcher inside:

```
using testing::ElementsAre;
using testing::Pair;

EXPECT_THAT(g.getOrdersToBeExecuted()), ElementsAre(Pair(key1, ElementsAre(e1, e2, e3)), Pair(key1, ElementsAre(e4, e5)));
```

Comment: I don't think I am using it correctly. Could you please see the edited qs?

Comment: You are comparing `Order` objects. Have you defined `operator==` for this class? Otherwise the compiler doesn't know how to tell they're equal.